# key.event confusion // pygame.K_a doesn't work

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new in this python industry, when i press 'd' my character should go right, but this isn t hapening, same thing to the 'a'. When I change K_a and K_d with K_LEFT and K_RIGHT it works, my character is moving well, but if I wanna make the character move with 'a' and 'd', it doesn't work, what's wrong with my code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import os

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1366,768))

pygame.display.set_caption("Adventure in the Woods")
icon = pygame.image.load('tree.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

#Player
playerImg = pygame.image.load('ninja.png')
playerX = 100
playerY = 650
velocity = 0.1

run = True
while run:

    screen.fill( (9, 66, 2) )
    screen.blit(playerImg, (playerX,playerY) )

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            print('a')
            playerX -= velocity
        
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            print('d')
            playerX += velocity
        

             
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Your `if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:` check needs to be indented another level, so that it is inside the `for event in pygame.event.get():` loop.  Currently, you are only checking the final event in the queue for your keypresses - apparently different types of keypresses are appearing at different positions in the queue.

Comment: Ok, I think I see *why* the queue differs - non-textual keys such as the arrow keys produce only a `KEYDOWN` event, but actual letters produce both a `KEYDOWN` and a `TEXTINPUT` event.  Your current code only sees the `TEXTINPUT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem Insight

The problem lies in the scope of your `if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: ...` as it should be within the for-loop `for event in pygame.event.get(): ...` :

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False

if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: #<-------------- From here
    if event.key == pygame.K_a:
        print('a')
        playerX -= velocity
    
    if event.key == pygame.K_d:
        print('d')
        playerX += velocity     #<-------------- to here
```

---

### Solution

This can be fixed by indenting the code block starting from `if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: ...`, like so:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: #<-------------- Now inside the for-loop
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            print('a')
            playerX -= velocity
    
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            print('d')
            playerX += velocity
```

---

### Other Remarks

To be more familiar with python code structures and styles, review some of the fundamental syntaxes like Indentation by visiting the style guide @ https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

*Cheers!*